# Terminology: Non-empty interior sets and non-dense sets

Tags: general-topology, terminology

This question is related to my previous post: [Is to be nowhere dense stronger than to have empty interior?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513790/is-to-be-nowhere-dense-stronger-than-to-have-empty-interior)

Recall that a set $A$ in a space $X$ has empty interior if its interior is empty (obviously) and that $A$ is dense if its closure is $X$.

It can be shown that $A$ has empty interior if and only if $X\setminus A$ is dense. But not every set which has non-empty interior is dense, and not every set which is not dense has empty interior.

Is there a standard terminology for those sets (apart from being called non-dense and having non-empty interior)?

Comment: I believe in last part of 3rd paragraph you meant to say "has non-empty" interior. Also, I don't know of any such terminology. One related thing is nowhere dense set, which you can easily look up for.

Comment: An $A$ with empty interior can be called “co-dense”.  AFAIK there is no standard term for a set that is neither dense nor co-dense.

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize, there are “three levels” of these properties:

*open dense $\implies$ dense interior $\implies$ dense*,

and the dual properties (properties of the complement)

*closed nowhere dense $\implies$ nowhere dense $\implies$ co-dense (empty interior)*

Sometimes there is confusion when someone first meets dense and nowhere dense sets. They seem to be dual properties, but they are not as the diagram shows.

Usually there are no special names for negations of properties, we may use non-dense, non-co-dense, non-open, non-meager, ... I personally use *bi-dense* for a dense set with a dense complement.